# React Native custom bottom tab bar cant change icon color

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

Im having problem with changing icon color when tabBarItem is pressed in my custom made BottomTabBar.

It seems that in the options of the screen tabIcon prop is not returning focused element.
I think that i need to trigger callback on item press but cant find docs how to do that.

My TabNavigator

```
     <Tab.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          tabBarActiveTintColor: "black",
          tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'gray',
        }}
        tabBar={props => <CustomTabBarV2 {...props}/>}
      >
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Screen1} 
          options={{
            title: 'Home',
            tabBarIcon: ({isFocused}) => { 
              console.log(isFocused)  ---------------> isFocused is undefined, dont know how to trigger callback
              return <AntDesign name="home" size={24} color={'black'}/>
            }
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen name="News"  component={Screen2} 
            options={{
              title: 'News',
              tabBarIcon: ({isFocused}) => <Ionicons name="newspaper-outline" size={24} color="black" />,
            }}
        />

        <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Screen5}   options={{
          title: 'Profile',
          tabBarIcon: ({isFocused}) => <MaterialIcons name="account-circle" size={24} color="black" />,
        }}/>

        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Screen3}  
          options={{
            title: 'Settings',
            tabBarIcon: ({isFocused}) => <Ionicons name="settings-outline" size={24} color="black" />,
          }} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Control" component={Screen4}  
          options={{
            title: 'Control',
            tabBarIcon: ({isFocused}) => <Ionicons name="scan" size={24} color="black" />,
          }} />
       
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

CustomTabBar.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';

import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';

import { primaryColor, secondaryColor } from '../styles/colors';
import Animated, { useAnimatedStyle, useSharedValue, withSpring } from 'react-native-reanimated';

interface Props {
    state: any;
    descriptors: any;
    navigation: any;
}

const CustomTabBarV2 : React.FC<Props> = ({state, navigation, descriptors}) => { 
    const {bottom} = useSafeAreaInsets()
    const navItemsRef = useRef(new Array())

    // Anim init value
    const sharedVal = useSharedValue(3);
    const [pillWidth, setPillWidth] = useState<number>(0)
    const [pillHeight, setPillHeight] = useState<number>(0)
  
  
    const animatedStyles = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
        return {
          transform: [{ translateX: sharedVal.value}]
        };
      });
    

    const onPress = (index: number) => {
      console.log(state.routes[index].key === descriptors)


      navItemsRef.current[index].measure((x: number, y: number, width: number, height: number, px: number, py: number) =>
      {
        sharedVal.value = withSpring(x - 7, { // - 7 for the pill to be centered
          damping: 10,
          mass: 0.4
        }) 
        setPillWidth(width + 15)  // + 15 for the pill to be larger than the navItemBox
        setPillHeight(height)
      })
      navigation.navigate({ name: state.routes[index].name, merge: true });
    };
 
    return (
        <View style={[styles.container, {paddingBottom: bottom, paddingHorizontal: 10}]}>
            <Animated.View style={[animatedStyles, {
              width: pillWidth,
              height: pillHeight ,
              backgroundColor: primaryColor,
              position: 'absolute',
              borderRadius: 10
            }]}/>
            
            {state.routes.map((route: any, index: number) => {
              const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
              const label : string =
                options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
                  ? options.tabBarLabel
                  : options.title !== undefined
                  ? options.title
                  : route.name;
      
              const isFocused: boolean = state.index === index;
              
             
      
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  onLayout={event => {
                      const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
                      setPillWidth(layout.width  + 15)
                      setPillHeight(layout.height)
                  }}
                  ref={(element) => navItemsRef.current.push(element)}
                  key={index}
                  accessibilityRole="button"
                  accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
                  accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
                  testID={options.tabBarTestID}
                  onPress={() => onPress(index)}
                  style={{ 
                    flex: 1,
                    justifyContent: 'center', 
                    flexDirection: 'row', 
                    alignItems: 'center',
                  }}>

                  
                  { isFocused ? 
                    <View
                      style={{ 
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        flexDirection: 'row', 
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        paddingVertical: 10,
                        paddingHorizontal: 20,
                        borderRadius: 30,
                      }}>
                      {options.tabBarIcon()}
                      <Animated.View style={[{justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}]}>
                        <Text style={[{ color: isFocused ? options.tabBarActiveTintColor : options.tabBarInactiveTintColor, marginLeft: 2, width: '100%', textAlign: 'center' }]}>
                          {label}
                        </Text>
                      </Animated.View>

                  </View> : 
                    <View
                    style={{ 
                      justifyContent: 'center',
                      flexDirection: 'row', 
                      alignItems: 'center', 
                      paddingVertical: 10,
                      paddingHorizontal: 20,
                      borderRadius: 30,
                    }}>
                      {options.tabBarIcon()}
                    </View>
                  }
                
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            })}
        </View>
      );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        height: 80,
        backgroundColor: secondaryColor,
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
});

export default CustomTabBarV2
```

Answer (score 0):

`isFocused` does not exist on `tabBarIcon`. You should use `focused` instead.

These are the expected types:

```js
tabBarIcon?: ((props: {
    focused: boolean;
    color: string;
    size: number;
}) => React.ReactNode) | undefined
```

Comment: my bad, i ment {focused} prop.

tabBarIcon doesnt recieve any props when i use customTabBar.
Not altering default tab bar works as expected.